# UICollectionView Reload Data Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My collectionView displays images of characters that have been added as a favorite. This is persisted in Core Data.

On a detail view controller, the user clicks the favorite button which adds the character to favorites. When it is clicked again, the figure is removed.

The problem is the images in the collection view are not updated without closing the app and re-running. I tried using:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.favoriteCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

But this was unsuccessful. How can I get the collection view to update?

UPDATE: Here is all that is in the cellForItemAt function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ownedCell", for: indexPath) as! OwnedCollectionViewCell

cell.ownedFigImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: favFigArray[indexPath.row]))

return cell
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` and check if you are loading correct data when you call `reloadData`

Comment: The only real code in that section is setting the cell's image based on my array.

Comment: Where does the `favFigArray` data come from? Are you positive it contains the url you are expecting when `reloadData()` is called?

Comment: I think the root cause is the image cached because you're using sd_setImage

Comment: Is `favFigArray` changed, adding/removing items?

Comment: The data in favFigArray is just a fetch from core data. All adding/removing of data occurs in the detail view controller. favFigArray is then updated with this data. I know the array is updating properly because I am printing the array. If it makes a difference the detail view controller is one tab and the collection view is another tab in a tab bar controller.

Comment: @Scott.N do you know of any work arounds?

Comment: If the array is updating properly and image save on local, let try `cell.ownedFigImage.image = UIImage(named: favFigArray[indexPath.row])`